# JPA criteria query order by - fetches duplicate records

Tags: hibernate, jpa, inheritance, sql-order-by

Hiiii,
I'm using J2EE with JPA 2.1 EclipseLink implementation on a project. My OS is Windows10.
I'm trying to order all my users according to their username (table ID).
I've a super calss "Utilisateur" and 2 subclasses "RespAudit" and "MembreAudit" implemented as follow:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "UTILISATEUR", catalog = "", schema = "HSEMS_DB")
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    public class Utilisateur implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
        @Column(name = "IDUSER")
        private String iduser;

        @Pattern(regexp = "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message = "E-mail invalide!")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
        @Size(max = 255)
        @Column(name = "EMAIL")
        private String email;

        @Size(min = 2, max = 255, message = "Taille du champ invalide!")
        @Column(name = "NOM")
        private String nom;

        @Size(min = 2, max = 255, message = "Taille du champ invalide")
        @Column(name = "PRENOM")
        private String prenom;

        @Size(min = 8, message = "La taille du mot de passe doit etre entre 8 et 20 caractères")
        @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
        private String password;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "utilisateur",cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
        private List<Commentaire> commentaireList = new ArrayList<>();

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "utilisateur",cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
        private List<JournalLog> LogList = new ArrayList<>();

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "utilisateur",cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
        private List<Fichier> filesList = new ArrayList<>();}
```

then it child Respaudit

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "RESPAUDIT", catalog = "", schema = "HSEMS_DB")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "IDUSER")

    public class Respaudit extends Utilisateur implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @JoinColumn(name = "respAudit", referencedColumnName = "equipe")
        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, mappedBy = "respAudit")
        private Auditeur equipe;
    }
```

followed by it last child **Membraudit**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "MEMBREAUDIT", catalog = "", schema = "HSEMS_DB")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "IDUSER")

    public class Membreaudit extends Utilisateur implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @JoinColumn(name = "IDEQUIPE")
        @ManyToOne
        private Auditeur equipe;

       @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idMembre", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
        private List<Affectation> affectationList;
    }
```

When I use order by method on subtables to sort the records. It's giving duplicated records.
I've tried to use "distinct" method as shown in the following findAll method but it seems without effect.

```
public List<T> findAll(String attribute) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        cq.orderBy(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().asc(cq.from(entityClass).get(attribute))).distinct(true);
        List<T> myList = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
        return myList;
    }
```

Can any one let me know how to do it without duplicates ? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: please provide more details :) 
like how is your query built and some code sample so we can help you